# how can I select one image among many in android?

Tags: android

I am developing a game in android.I have many ImageViews displayed on canvas and I am using emulator.Now I want to select a specific image and want to rotate it.As I am using emulator I cant use ontouchListener.Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you develop in endengine or OpenGl?

Comment: i thing there should be object.setEntity(intvalue);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onTouchListener possible in the emulator. use touch listener's for images u will get the image when u click on image.

Answer (score 0):

The onTouchListener and onClickListeners are attached to views. You cannot do that to bitmaps. So if you want to click and rotate an image you will need to put the image in an imageview and try to rotate it.

Comment: how can I drag image on emulator?

Comment: @user996518 were you able to solve the problem of having to select only one image among many using onclicklistener/ontouchlistener?